# Application with map gestion

Tags: openstreetmap

Im looking for an application that allow you to place points on map, and create a file like xls or something with those points, as main functionnality.

Does it already exist ?

Or is it easier to create my own ? 
I dont know anything about the map api's, would be an wpf app in c# if you got some link to begin that would be amazing

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Take a look at uMap, Leaflet or OpenLayers. Not much coding necessary.